# Let user select file in customizer

Tags: theme-customizer

In wordpress theme cutomizer I want user to be able to select a file from media Library. Similarly as with `WP_Customize_Image_Control`, but I want him to be able to select any file not only an image.

Is there any way to do that? I will be grateful for any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found a controll I was looking for. I can use the `WP_Customize_Upload_Control` class.

More info can be found in [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Upload_Control)